# web connection with python

Tags: python, web.py

I have this code to create a webapp in my server:

```
import web

urls = (
    '/update', 'Update',
)

app = web.application(urls, globals())


class Update:

    print "hola"

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run()
```

When I try to execute:

```
python@ubuntu:~$ python prueba.py 8081
hola
http://0.0.0.0:8081/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prueba.py", line 21, in <module>
    app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/web/application.py", line 311, in run
    return wsgi.runwsgi(self.wsgifunc(*middleware))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/web/wsgi.py", line 54, in runwsgi
    return httpserver.runsimple(func, validip(listget(sys.argv, 1, '')))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/web/httpserver.py", line 148, in runsimple
    server.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/web/wsgiserver/__init__.py", line 1753, in start
    raise socket.error(msg)
socket.error: No socket could be created
```

Why is it happening?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Added the web.py tag (since that's what you're using here).  Hopefully now, one of those gurus will find this question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running python app on localhost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9322284/running-python-app-on-localhost)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message says that it couldn't create a listening socket on the specified port. Check if there is already a server running on port 8081.

Comment: Nope, that would yield the error message `[Errno 98] Address already in use`

Comment: Oh my god! it was so easy! that was the mistake, thank you so much